# Flutterflow app with multiple businesses and seperate accounts

Tags: flutterflow

Evening all.

I am trying to work out the final details of an app i am building. I like the idea of being able to release it to the public once completed.

Lets say i have a database app for equipment and inventory tracking.
Company 1 has multiple users that will log in.

When/If i was to make the app available to the public. and say Company 2 creates an account.
How can i develope the app so that Company 1 and its users only see their information. And Company 2 can only see and edit theirs?

Lets just say there are now 15 companies, and each company has 10 users. I am best off creating the app 15 times? or is there a better way of doing this? Whats best practice?

Cheers

I have yet to try anything as i am reaching out to those that know better :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.